# What can be done to plastic to make it reflect and refract light?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, refraction

This may belong in a DIY but I think it's still relevant. The scenario is simple: I have a red laser pointer, and a piece of red, translucent, hard plastic. My goal is as such: when I fire the laser pointer at the plastic, the plastic glows red as much as possible.

My theory is to modify the back side of the plastic such that the pointer light is reflected a bit, and also refracted. I thought I would ask the professionals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple links that might help. http://studiorob.blogspot.com/2010/11/edge-glow-acrylic-plastic.html or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kuaH3EHeSg

Note that you see the light where the plastic is rough in one case. In the other case, the plastic is smooth.

Rough plastic scatters light that strikes it in all directions. Some light is sent toward your eye.

Smooth plastic reflects light that strikes at a grazing angle back inside. Since the light is reflected back inside, you don't see light there. When it reaches the edge, it strikes head on and escapes. That is where you see it.

Comment: Your link and info led me to search for Laser Targets. It looks like phosphorous materials are helpful and something called Rare Earth Europium.